# New servicestack project navigates to localhost/metadata, not localhost/folder/metadata

Tags: c#, iis, servicestack

I'm starting a new servicestack project. I have it set up for local IIS (which works fine for my old ss project). When I navigate to the url, which should be http://localhost/NewSvc, my browser switches quickly to localhost/metadata, with a 404 error.  If I manually type http://localhost/NewSvc/metadata into the browser, then I see my new service metadata page.  But using the site name alone won't work, either from IIS, debugging in Visual Studio, or directly from the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceStack **v4.5.13** that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget) should resolve this issue with IIS Virtual Directories.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue with my ServiceStack nuget package being v4.5.12, I reverted it to v4.5.10 and it resolved my issue.